# ¿como puedo conectarme desde PHP a una base de datos Access con extensión .accdb?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, odbc

Muy buenas, quiero conectarme desde `PHP` a una base de datos `access` con extensión *.accdb* pero recibo este error.

> *Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][Administrador de controladores ODBC] La arquitectura del DSN especificado no coincide
>   entre el controlador y la aplicaci�n.*

He creado en el Administrador de origen de datos `ODBC` (64 bits) un `DSN` de sistema de nombre "base" usando el controlador `"Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)`.

El código que he usado para conexión es el siguiente:

```
$dsn = "base"; 
$usuario = "";
$clave="";

$cid=odbc_connect($dsn,$usuario,$clave);
```

El sistema operativo es windows 10, la versión de `access` con la que se ha creado al base de datos es 2013 y el `PHP` esta funcionando sobre `XAMPP`.

Comment: Mira si [este hilo](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/de546e27-f31b-48d9-a0fb-074c18f755de/problema-con-odbc-nuevo?forum=dotnetes), te puede servir.

Comment: Ese hilo ya lo vi, pero a mi no me vale, creo que es para formatos antiguos de bases de datos access, de echo intente seguirlo pero el driver de Microsoft Access Driver no admite bases de datos con extensión .accdb que es la mía, de todas formas gracias por tu pronta respuesta.

Comment: He rehecho todo de 0 en un ordenador nuevo y funciona perfectamente, al parecer el problema es del ordenador con el que estaba haciendo las pruebas, tiene algo mal con el "Microsoft Acces Driver".